# Powerpivot; Get a datadump from SQL vs creating a data model in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, powerpivot

I have a SQL table that includes sales and lead data along with detailed account information, and I have another table that just includes detailed account information.

My question is whether it is more efficient to pull just the sales figure and account ID (exclude the detailed account information), and pull a separate table that contains just detailed account information, then crate relationship in powerpivot using the account ID. OR is it more efficient/faster to just dump taht one table that contains all the information to powerpivot (all the work is done in SQL).

First, I thought since information such as account managers, segments, and account name would be duplicated for many sales figures (account A could buy multiple products multiple times), having a separate table which contains just the account information would be more efficient. 
But more I think about this, if I have two tables, excel would have to do all the work on the fly instead of letting SQL handle all the work.

Would love to hear the experts' opinion on this. I need powerbi/powerpivot to work fast, even if this means less memory efficient excel.

Answer (score 0):

Separate tables will definitely be faster to refresh and analyze using Pivot Tables, and also be more compact (on disk and in memory).

That design also opens the possibility of efficient Account-level calculations (if you need them later on) e.g. distinct count of products per account.

The gotcha can be that data sets are often dirty and supposed keys are often unreliable - this problem usually gets worse the further back you go in history.  Those issues may force you back to a single table design in Power Pivot, so that you can try to fudge around those issues using SQL code, Power Query or an ETL tool.

Comment: From performance perspective (faster response time in pivot/Q&A), would it be faster if the data is on the single table vs on separate table? I'm not too worried about the faster query (if you mean process during refresh) as the query is already being executed nightly.

Comment: yes sorry I slipped into SSAS terminology - I meant "refresh" rather than "process", and I meant "analyze using Pivot Tables" rahter than and "query".  I'll edit my answer.